# Mocha with TypeScript: Parameter 'id' implicitly has an 'any' type?

Tags: typescript, mocha.js

I wrote a simple function as follows:

```
export const courseIndustry: any = {
  getById: (id: string) => {
    return {};
  }
};
```

And I thought I specified that the argument id is of type string, but the `mocha test` claims:

```
mocha -r ts-node/register -r espower-typescript/guess test/**/*.test.ts

Unable to compile TypeScript: courseIndustry.ts(4, 15): error TS7006:  Parameter 'id' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error seems thrown by espower-typescript/guess. So I checked its document and find the following switch can work around the errors: 'TS_NODE_TRANSPILE_ONLY=1'.

So the final version of the shell command make it work:

```
TS_NODE_TRANSPILE_ONLY=1 mocha -r ts-node/register --require espower-typescript/guess test/**/*.test.ts --exit
```

Comment: This works. Semantically it makes sense, because even though typescript errors are urgent, they need to be addressed in development time, in testing time the only thing we are worried about is the unit tests actually passing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a another transpiler like typescript-compiler or any other and try to complie.

[enter link description here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-compiler)

Comment: Can I use it with Mocha?

Comment: yeah i think it's not an issue because mocha is just a js framework.and the above is just a transpiler