# Another TS7006: Parameter "X" implicitly has an "any" type – but not quite

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, webdriver-io

I know there are tons of questions/answers related with this issue, and as far as I can tell, I understand the nature of it, but I can't understand why would it happen on types I explicitly set and control.

I have purposely set `noImplicitAny` to `true` inside `tsconfig.json`; I know that if I turn it to `false` this issue will go away – but I don't want to do that...yet :)

This is the code:

```
# ./src/page/base.page.ts
export default class BasePage {
  public open(path: string) {
    browser.url(path);
  }
}
```

---

```
# ./src/page/home-search.page.ts
import BasePage from "./base.page";

class HomeSearchPage extends BasePage {
  public fillForm(term: string) {
    $("#search_form_input_homepage").setValue(term);
  }

  public open() {
    super.open(`${browser.options.baseUrl}`);
  }

  public submit() {
    $("#search_button_homepage").click();
  }
}

export default new HomeSearchPage();
```

---

```
# ./test/spec/search.engine.spec.ts
import HomeSearchPage from "@page/home-search.page";
import { expect } from "chai";

describe("DuckDuckGo (DDG) Search Engine", () => {
  it("Verify search result(s) for given term", () => {
    const expected: string = "WebdriverIO · Next-gen WebDriver test framework for Node.js";
    const input: string = "webdriverio";

    HomeSearchPage.open();
    HomeSearchPage.fillForm(input);
    HomeSearchPage.submit();

    expect($("div#r1-0 h2.result__title a.result__a").getText()).to.contain(expected);
  });
});
```

...and finally, my `tsconfig.json` (located at project's root):

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["./*"],
      "@page/*": ["./src/page/*"]
    },
    "removeComments": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2018",
    "types": [
      "@wdio/mocha-framework",
      "@wdio/sync",
      "@types/chai",
      "@types/mocha",
      "node"
    ],

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //  Experimental Settings
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    "noImplicitAny": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules/"],
  "include": ["./src/**/*", "./test/**/*"]
}
```

With that setup, I'm always getting the same error message:

```
[0-0] RUNNING in chrome - /test/spec/search.engine.spec.ts
0-0 worker error { name: 'TSError',
  message:
   '⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:\nsrc/page/home-search.page.ts(5,14): error TS7006: Parameter \'term\' implicitly has an \'any\' type.\n',
  stack:
   'TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:\nsrc/page/home-search.page.ts(5,14): error TS7006: Parameter \'term\' implicitly has an \'any\' type.\n\n    at createTSError
...
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)' }
[0-0] FAILED in chrome - /test/spec/search.engine.spec.ts
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that class even though the error is point to the class that i can see

Comment: Yeah, same here. The error makes no sense for me, but there is got to be something...

Comment: is there a error in the file in your IDE? because im suspecting its something to do with how your tests are compiling those files; if there's no error in the IDE its a compilation issue with whatever pipeline your tests are running those files through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is coming from `ts-node`.  In your `wdio.conf.js`, change your `before: function()` to this:

```js
  before: function (capabilities, specs) {
    require("ts-node").register({ files: true, transpileOnly: true });
  },
```

[This question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52886918/mocha-with-typescript-parameter-id-implicitly-has-an-any-type) also mentioned a very similar issue to what you were experiencing.  I pulled your repo down locally and got the test to run successfully.